# Get report parameters as URL string

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net, reporting-services

I have an application that serves SSRS reports. A given report is accessed in the following way:

```
https://reportserver.com/reportname
```

Upon clicking **View Report**, a postback is submitted to the report server with the user-defined parameters. I need to grab these user-defined parameters and parse them as a URL string.

**Desired result:** `https://reportserver.com/reportname?param1=foo&param2=bar`

I found [this doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.reportparameterseventargs.parameters.aspx) that gets me close to what I need. This method should allow me to grab all visible parameters and parse them myself, but I need **hidden parameters** as well.

How can I build this parameter string? We're using JavaScript/jQuery in the front end so it may be possible to grab this client-side before the POST, but I haven't found a way of doing this either.

Comment: Can you explain why you're after the parameters? Is it for trouble-shooting user issues? Do you want to see which parameter values are being used the most?

Comment: Sure. I want to make a way for users to bookmark reports with their parameters, and I'm doing that using a button that is a href to the report itself with the query string attached. They can then save that link for future use.

Comment: Here's an example of the execution log in a report using the 3 option. https://github.com/SQL-Server-projects/Reporting-Services-examples/blob/master/ServerReports/Execution%20Log.rdl

Comment: You can setup the report to filter by the current user

Comment: I'd also use a functional account to run the dataset, because users won't have permissions to query the reportserver.

Comment: Did the execution log report sort you out?

Comment: Yes and no... I'm querying the execution log from the report viewer control's code behind, but I haven't found a way to fire a function when the report is fully rendered. I tried using a `Load` event but that fires too early, grabbing the second most recent log before the current report is finished rendering.

Comment: Have you tried the ReportViewer1.RenderingComplete event?

Comment: Sadly, this won't work either, as we're not using WinForms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it working. Fair warning: I'm new to ASP.NET so this is likely not an ideal solution.

I added an event handler to the report viewer control's code behind. This queries the execution log, grabbing the parameters selected most recently by the user. It is meant to be triggered when a button called "Save Report" is clicked. If you try to handle this with a `Load` or `PreRender` event handler it will fire before the row has a chance to insert into the database, giving you the result of the user's second most recent execution parameters.

**Define the Button (.ascx file)**

```
  <asp:LinkButton ID="SaveReportButton" runat="server" title="Save this Report"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Add event handler to code behind (.ascx.vb file)**

```
Protected Sub SaveReportButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveReportButton.Click
  Dim conn As New SqlConnection(<connection string here>)
  Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT TOP 1 Parameters FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[ExecutionLogStorage] WHERE <qualify on user, timestamp, etc. here>", conn)
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(<query parameter here>)
  conn.Open()
  Dim result = cmd.ExecuteScalar()

  ' Prevents NullReferenceException from result.ToString() in case no result is found
  If (result IsNot Nothing)

    ' Redirect based on parameter string retrieved from log
    Response.Redirect(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri & "?" & result.ToString())

  End If
  conn.Close()
End Sub
```

**Call postback from JavaScript on button click**

```
<li>
  <a href=\'javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(<reference SaveReportButton with appropriate arguments>)\' id="SaveReportButton" title="Save Report">
  Save Report
  </a>
</li>
```

Documentation on `WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions()` and `WebForm_PostBackOptions()` is sparse, but a colleague has already done it this way so I followed suit <s>for consistency's sake</s> because it works.

Answer (score 3):

I've created URLs for reports with parameters 3 different ways. A combination of the the first two may get you closer to solving your problem.

Use custom code in the report properties.

```
Public Function ShowParameterValues(ByVal parameter As Parameter) As String  
Dim s as String = String.Empty 
    Try
       If parameter.IsMultiValue then  
          s = "Multivalue: "   
          For i as integer = 0 to parameter.Count-1  
             s = s + CStr(parameter.Value(i)) + " "   
          Next  
       Else  
          s = "Single value: " + CStr(parameter.Value)  
       End If  
       Return s  

    Catch ex As Exception
        Return "error"

    End Try

End Function
```

OR

Use a hyperlink in the report.

```
=Globals!ReportServerUrl + "/ReportServer?" 
 + Replace(Globals!ReportFolder, " ", "+") + "%2f" 
 + Replace(Globals!ReportName, " ", "+") + "&rs:Command=Render"
 + "&boolean_value=" + CStr(Parameters!boolean_value.Value)
 + "&single_value_parameter=" + Parameters!single_value_parameter.Value 
 + "&multi_value_parameter=" + Join(Parameters!multi_value_parameter.Value, "&multi_value_parameter=") 
 + IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!week_date_start.Value), "&week_date_start:isnull=True", "&week_date_start=" & Format(Parameters!week_date_start.Value, Variables!FormatDate.Value))
 + IIf(IsNothing(Parameters!week_date_end.Value), "&week_date_end:isnull=True", "&week_date_end=" & Format(Parameters!week_date_end.Value, Variables!FormatDate.Value))
```

Also, I usually add this as a report variable and then you can have a standard textbox for the footer that doesn't have to change.

```
=Variables!UrlReportWithParameters.Value
```

OR

Use the execution log. Check out the column `URL_Report_Filtered`

```
--Purpose:  to search the reporting services execution log

DECLARE @all_value AS VARCHAR(10) = '<ALL>';
DECLARE @LogStatus AS VARCHAR(50) = '<ALL>';
DECLARE @ReportFolder AS VARCHAR(450) = 'Testing';
DECLARE @ReportName AS VARCHAR(450) = '<ALL>';
DECLARE @UserName AS VARCHAR(260) = '<ALL>';
DECLARE @GroupByColumn AS VARCHAR(50) = 'Report Folder';
DECLARE @StartDate AS DATETIME = NULL;
DECLARE @EndDate AS DATETIME = NULL;

WITH
report_users 
AS
(
    SELECT 
          [UserID]
        , [UserName]
        , [SimpleUserName] = UPPER(RIGHT([UserName], (LEN([UserName])-CHARINDEX('\',[UserName])))) 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Users]
)
,
report_catalog
AS
(
    SELECT    
          rpt.[ItemID]
        , rpt.[CreatedById]
        , rpt.[ModifiedById]
        , rpt.[Type]
        , rpt.[Name] 
        , [ReportName] = rpt.[Name] 
        , rpt.[Description]
        , rpt.[Parameter]
        , [CreationDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), rpt.[CreationDate], 13))
        , [ModifiedDate] = CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), rpt.[ModifiedDate], 13))
        , [ReportFolder] = SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, LEN(rpt.[Path])-LEN(rpt.[Name])-2) 
        , rpt.[Path]
        , [URL_ReportFolder] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f'  + SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, LEN(rpt.[Path])-LEN(rpt.[Name])-2)  + '&ViewMode=List'
        , [URL_Report] = 'http://' + Host_Name() + '/Reports/Pages/Report.aspx?ItemPath=%2f'  + SUBSTRING(rpt.[Path], 2, LEN(rpt.[Path])-LEN(rpt.[Name])-2)  + '%2f' + rpt.[Name]
        , [ReportDefinition] = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), rpt.[Content]))  
        , [HostName] = Host_Name()
    FROM 
        [dbo].[Catalog] AS rpt
    WHERE 
        1=1
        AND rpt.[Type] = 2
)
SELECT 
    [GroupBy1] = 
        CASE  
            WHEN @GroupByColumn = 'Report Name' THEN rpt.[ReportName]
            WHEN @GroupByColumn = 'Report Folder' THEN rpt.[ReportFolder]
            WHEN @GroupByColumn = 'User Id' THEN usr.[SimpleUserName]
            ELSE '<N/A>' 
        END
    , rpt.[Path]
    , rpt.[ReportFolder]
    , rpt.[Name]
    , rpt.[URL_ReportFolder]
    , rpt.[URL_Report] 
    , [URL_Report_Filtered] = rpt.[URL_Report] + '&rs:Command=Render&' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(max), el.[Parameters])
    , [UserName] = usr.[SimpleUserName]
    , el.[Status]
    , el.[TimeStart]
    , el.[RowCount]
    , el.[ByteCount]
    , el.[Format]
    , el.[Parameters]
    , [TotalSeconds] = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms,(el.[TimeDataRetrieval] + el.[TimeProcessing] + el.[TimeRendering]),0),108)
    , [TimeDataRetrieval] = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms,el.[TimeDataRetrieval],0),108) 
    , [TimeProcessing] = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms,el.[TimeProcessing],0),108)  
    , [TimeRendering] = CONVERT(CHAR(8),DATEADD(ms,el.[TimeRendering],0),108) 
    , [OrderbyDate] = CAST([TimeStart] AS DATETIME) 
FROM 
    report_catalog AS rpt 
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[ExecutionLog] AS el ON el.[ReportID] = rpt.[ItemID]
    LEFT JOIN report_users AS usr ON el.[UserName] = usr.[UserName]
WHERE 
    1=1
    AND (@all_value IN(@LogStatus) OR el.[Status] IN(@LogStatus))
    AND (@all_value IN (@ReportFolder) OR rpt.[ReportFolder] IN(@ReportFolder))
    AND (@all_value IN(@ReportName) OR rpt.[ReportName] IN(@ReportName))
    AND (@all_value IN(@UserName) OR usr.[SimpleUserName] IN(@UserName))
    AND (@StartDate IS NULL OR CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), el.[TimeStart], 13)) >= @StartDate)
    AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), el.[TimeStart], 13)) <= @EndDate)
```

Comment: We have over 1200 reports so adding custom code to each is not an option, unfortunately. I tried using a shared dataset to query the execution log, but the execution log was updated after that dataset ran.

Comment: I ended up having to handle this server side due to the sheer number of reports I'm dealing with. However your answer is excellent and certainly has my upvote. Thank you for steering me in the right direction!